# If statement works in console but doesn't work otherwise (If statement with select value)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is a very beginner question but I've tried searching for answers and can't find anything. Would appreciate any insight. I know how to get the code to work because I've seen an example with better/proper code. My question is why MY code won't work (even if it's not optimal, I don't understand why it doesn't at least work). It works when I plug it into the console but not when I open the page.

So the program is just a simple Scorekeeper. The buttons are supposed to disable when "play until" score is hit by either player so the game has to be reset to work again. But even when I check the booleans in console and they're returning true and the If Statement runs, it still doesn't work on the page. The button's don't disable.

ex. if winningScore is 5 and scoreOne.innerText is '5' and I put in winningScore === parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) when they're the same number the If Statement actually runs in console.

Editing to mention that winningScore is default set to 3 but is subject to change upon a select 'change' event. const points is a select html element with 3 options with values of 3, 5, and 7.

The code (not sure if I should post the whole thing or cut out the seemingly irrelevant parts):

```js
const scoreOne = document.querySelector('#scoreOne');
const scoreTwo = document.querySelector('#scoreTwo');
const scoreOneUp = document.querySelector('#scoreOneUp');
const scoreOneDown = document.querySelector('#scoreOneDown');
const scoreTwoUp = document.querySelector('#scoreTwoUp');
const scoreTwoDown = document.querySelector('#scoreTwoDown');
const reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
const points = document.querySelector('#points');
let winningScore = 3;
    
points.addEventListener('change', function() {
  winningScore = parseInt(this.value);
  });

//this code here !!!! doesn't run
if (winningScore == parseInt(scoreOne.innerText)) {
    scoreOne.style.color = 'green';
    scoreTwo.style.color = 'red';
    scoreOneUp.disabled = true;
    scoreTwoUp.disabled = true;
    scoreOneDown.disabled = true;
    scoreTwoDown.disabled = true;
  } else if (winningScore == parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText)) {
    scoresTwo.style.color = 'green';
    scoresOne.style.color = 'red';
    scoreOneUp.disabled = true;
    scoreTwoUp.disabled = true;
    scoreOneDown.disabled = true;
    scoreTwoDown.disabled = true;
  }

scoreOneUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scoreOne.innerText = parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) + 1;
});

scoreOneDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) > 0) {
  scoreOne.innerText = parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) - 1;}
});

scoreTwoUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scoreTwo.innerText = parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) + 1;
});

scoreTwoDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) > 0) {
  scoreTwo.innerText = parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) - 1;}
});

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scoreOne.innerText = 0;
  scoreTwo.innerText = 0;
  scoreOneUp.disabled = false;
  scoreOneDown.disabled = false;
  scoreTwoUp.disabled = false;
  scoreTwoDown.disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<h1>Scorekeeper</h1>

<button id='reset'>Reset Scores</button>

<div class='player'>
<button class='up'>+</button>
<button class='down'>-</button>
<span id='scoreOne'>0</span>
</div>

<div class='player'>
    <button class='up'>+</button>
    <button class='down'>-</button>
    <span id='scoreTwo'>0</span>
</div>


<label for='points'>
    Play until:
  <select name='points' id='points'>
    <option value='3' selected>3</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
  </select>
  </label>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you tried to debug your code?

Comment: I'm admittedly very new to webdev and Javascript so I'm not really sure what you mean. There doesn't seem to be any errors caught by Visual Studio or the console?

Comment: What type of element is '#scoreOne'?  If it's a regular input then you should use 'value', not 'innerHTML'.

Comment: #scoreOne is just a span with 0 in it. <span id='scoreOne'>0</span> to show the score of player one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<head>
<style>
  body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .Section{
    width:15%;
    padding:3%;
    min-height:90%;
    background-color:darkgray;
    border-radius:5%;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .Score{
  padding-top:20%;
    
  }
  .button{
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:25%;
    padding: 2em;
    width:2em;
  }
  .yellow{
    background-color:yellow
  }
  .orange{

    background-color:orange  
  }
  .red{
  
    background-color:red
  }
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
  <div class="Section">
    <div id="scoreOneUp" class="button"> /\
    </div>
    <div class="button yellow">
    Player 1
    </div>
    <div id="scoreOne" class="button yellow"> 0
    </div>
    <div id="scoreOneDown" class="button"> \/
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Section Score">
    <div id="points" class="button orange"> 3
    </div>
    <div id="reset"  class="button red" > Reset
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Section">
  <div id="scoreTwoUp" class="button"> /\
    </div>
    <div class="button yellow">
    Player 2
    </div>
    <div id="scoreTwo" class="button yellow"> 0
    </div>
    <div id="scoreTwoDown" class="button"> \/
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const scoreOne = document.querySelector('#scoreOne');
  const scoreTwo = document.querySelector('#scoreTwo');
  const scoreOneUp = document.querySelector('#scoreOneUp');
  const scoreOneDown = document.querySelector('#scoreOneDown');
  const scoreTwoUp = document.querySelector('#scoreTwoUp');
  const scoreTwoDown = document.querySelector('#scoreTwoDown');
  const reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
  const points = document.querySelector('#points');

  points.addEventListener('change', function() {
    winningScore = parseInt(this.value);
    });

  function testScores(){
  
    let winningScore = 3;
    if (winningScore == parseInt(scoreOne.innerText)) {
      scoreOne.style.color = 'green';
      scoreTwo.style.color = 'red';
      scoreOne.disabled = true;
      scoreTwo.disabled = true;
    } else if (winningScore == parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText)) {
      scoreTwo.style.color = 'green';
      scoreOne.style.color = 'red';
      scoreOne.disabled = true;
      scoreTwo.disabled = true;
    }
  }


  scoreOneUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
   if (! scoreOne.disabled) {
      scoreOne.innerText = parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) + 1;
      testScores();
   }
  });

  scoreOneDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) > 0 && ! scoreOne.disabled) {
      scoreOne.innerText = parseInt(scoreOne.innerText) - 1;
    }
    testScores();
  });

  scoreTwoUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(!scoreTwo.disabled){
      scoreTwo.innerText = parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) + 1;
      testScores();
    }
  });

  scoreTwoDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) > 0 && !scoreTwo.disabled) {
    scoreTwo.innerText = parseInt(scoreTwo.innerText) - 1;}
    testScores();
  });

  reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    scoreOne.innerText = 0;
    scoreTwo.innerText = 0;
    scoreOne.disabled = false;
    scoreTwo.disabled = false;
  });
</script>
</body>
```

All Javascript code, unless called by a listener, will run once. By not putting your checker function in a function that can be called each time the score changes, it would always check the score once and never repeat.
Therefore, when you posted it into console, it was checking the score**at the time**, but it would run when both scores were 0 when it was put into your html body.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and clear explanation!! I really appreciate it! I don't have enough reputation to upvote you yet but I will when I do lol.

Comment: @kettlechips hey man no worries. Good luck , is this for football scores/ MTG? What's your end goal with it? 
You can also mark this as `answered` and I get sweet sweet S.O cred out of it <3

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was a thing haha. Marked as answered! It was just a suggested app for an online bootcamp "course" I'm taking and it was suggested to try and code it yourself before doing the follow along. The suggested code was far different and cleaner than what I came up with but I just had no idea why my code wasn't working and wanted to know for future reference.